# Why do 嬲, 嫐 mean "play with; flirt with; angry"?

Tags: etymology

Tianjin Qin's [answer](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/28229) alludes to the answer, but can you please expatiate the semantic relationship between  嬲 (Man-Woman-Man), 嫐 (Woman-Man-Woman) with teasing? Do 嬲, 嫐 symbolize  peer pressure or group bullying, where the two peers or bullies are entrapping, sandwiching, and thus pressuring the lone victim in the middle?

> To find out their difference, just consider them as pictographic characters, then what is the difference between teasing scenarios "Man-Woman-Man" and "Woman-Man-Woman"? You can imagine it, right?

Answer (score 1):

Baidu explains 嬲（niǎo）as：方言用字，很多时候用作脏词。通孬。在普通话中意为戏弄、搅扰，或纠缠之意。在内蒙古以及晋北方言中，意为：神气、得意，或志得意满之意。粤语中意为：生气。

Two men with a woman in middle is an intolerable/unspeakable dirty thing in the past, or even now.

https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%AC%B2/242954

On top of the meanings of 嬲, there is another meaning for 嫐 - 《康熙字典》： “娆，嫐也。”说明嫐另外还有娇媚、柔弱、妖娆、妩媚的意思。

Two women with a man in the middle, while dirty thing (sexual matters) happens, it also describes the scene that two women join together to please the more socially dominant male companion, such as 妃子和皇帝, 兩女共侍一夫(男), 風塵女子共侍一男客...

https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%AB%90/10331735

When two persons compete for a common trophy (the single opposite sex), "bullying and anger" are not difficult to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Its sort of like 'bunch' of people mingle together, and hence the rather flexible description of emotions, you know, like the ones you might see when people get together regarding 'something'.

Answer (score 0):

嬲 is a common Cantonese expression.

It means `angry`.

For example, 好嬲 means `very angry`.